# Index write costs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Here [Java Understanding write costs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/entities#Java_Understanding_write_costs) I was reading about optimizing my entities.

What I don't understand in the first line is

> When your application executes a Cloud Datastore put operation

I'm using NodeJs and the [NodeJs documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.3.x/Datastore) mentions no put command, hence I'm confused if the extra index write costs only applies to the Insert command or also to other commands like Update.

**Update**
I found this answer [Google Datastore new pricing effect operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509760/google-datastore-new-pricing-effect-operations)
from what I understand it doesn't matter if I let datastore automatically index my properties since I'm only charged once for each time an entity is inserted, updated and read.

I guess the only improvement I get by excluding indexes on some properties is decreased storage requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the amount of indexes [won't increase write costs](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/03/Google-Cloud-Datastore-simplifies-pricing-cuts-cost-dramatically-for-most-use-cases.html). Although they will be making use of [storage](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing#storage_size_consideration). You have the official [Datastore Pricing model here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing)